# problema basico en node js con las rutas

Tags: nodejs

Hola amigos estoy empezando a ver en node js y me sale este error:

```
root@sommer0123-AO532h:/home/sommer0123/Escritorio/Nodejs/estatica# node index.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './modulos/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (/home/sommer0123/Escritorio/Nodejs/estatica/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
root@sommer0123-AO532h:/home/sommer0123/Escritorio/Nodejs/estatica#
```

el problema como entiendo es la ruta pero la ruta esta bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sorry por el teclado tactil.

mi codigo:

index.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var servidor = require('./modulos/server');
servidor.crear(http, url, fs);
console.log('El servidor esta funcionando correctamente en http://localhost:3000/');
```

server.js

```
var mine_types = {
   'js' : 'text/javascript',
   'html' : 'text/html',
   'css' : 'text/css',
   'jpg' : 'image/jpg',
   'gif' : 'image/gif',
   'png' : 'image/png'
};
function crear(http, url, fs){
   http.createServer(function(peticion, respuesta){
      var ruta_a_archivo = devolverRutaArchivo(url, peticion);
      leerArchivo(fs, ruta_a_archivo, function(numero, contenido_archivo){
         if(numero === 404){
            respuesta.writeHead(numero, 'text/plain');
            respuesta.end('Error 404. El enlace no existe o ha dejado de existir.');
         }else if(numero === 500){
            respuesta.writeHead(numero, 'text/plain');
            respuesta.end('Error interno.');
         }else{
            var extension = ruta_a_archivo.split('.').pop();
            var mine_type = mine_types[extension];
            respuesta.writeHead(numero, {'Content-Type': mine_type});
            respuesta.end(contenido_archivo);
         }
      })
   }).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
}
function devolverRutaArchivo(url, peticion){
   var path_nombre = (url.parse(peticion.url).pathname == '/') ? '/index.html' : url.parse(peticion.url).pathname;
   var ruta_a_archivo = 'contenido/' + path_nombre;
   return ruta_a_archivo;
}
function leerArchivo(fs, ruta_a_archivo, callback){
   fs.exists(ruta_a_archivo, function(existe){
      if(existe){
         fs.readFile(ruta_a_archivo, function(error, contenido_archivo){
            if(error){
               callback(500, null);
            }else{
               callback(200, contenido_archivo);
            }
         });
      }else{
         callback(404, null);
      }
   });
}
exports.crear = crear;
```

animales.js

```
var lista = {
   'aves': new Array('Loro' , 'Canario'),
   'mamiferos': new Array('Perro' , 'Caballo' , 'Tigre'),
   'reptiles': new Array('Cocodrilo', 'Tortuga', 'Iguana')
};
function dibujarCodigoHtml(grupo){
   var html = '';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += ' Seleccione el tipo de animal: ';
   html += ' ' + listarGrupos(grupo) + ' ';
   html += '';
   html += '';
   html += listarAnimales(grupo);
   html += '';
   html += '';
   return html;
}
function listarGrupos(grupo){
   var html = ' --- ';
   var selected;
   for (var item in lista) {
      selected = (item == grupo) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
      html += ' ' + item + ' ';
   }
   return html;
}
function listarAnimales(grupo){
   var html = '';
   if(lista[grupo] != undefined){
      html += '';
      for (var i in lista[grupo]) {
         html += '' + lista[grupo][i] + '';
      }
      html += '';
   }
   return html;
}
exports.dibujarCodigoHtml = dibujarCodigoHtml;
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Ejemplo de Node.js </title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Index </h1>
   <ul>
      <li> <a href="/index.html"> Index </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/info.html"> Info </a> </li>
   </ul>
   <p> Bienvenido/a a la página principal </p>
</body>
</html>
```

info.html

```css
body {
   background-color: #D4ECF8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Ejemplo de Node.js </title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Info </h1>
   <ul>
      <li> <a href="/index.html"> Index </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/info.html"> Info </a> </li>
   </ul>
   <p> Esta es la página info </p>
</body>
</html>
```

origen del codigo con el que estoy usando:
http://fernando-gaitan.com.ar/introduccion-a-node-js-parte-3-crear-modulos/

img del error:

Comment: Trata dejandolo asi  `require(__dirname + '/modulos/server');`

Comment: Dejame ver y te aviso

Comment: Eso hice amigo pero como vez me tira el error indicándome que la ruta esta mal pero la ruta esta correctamente.

Comment: Pero desde la carpeta "estática"o cual?

Comment: Si tu index.js está en la carpeta estatica entonces debería de ser: `var servidor = require('./contenido/modulos/server');` imagino es que el problema es que tu carpeta modulos está dentro de contenido cuando debería de estar al mismo nivel

Comment: Pero disculpen pero si vez en el código index.js importo a ser ver.js ,porque me comentas que lo ejecutes?

Comment: @gilbertoquintero por eso borre mis comentarios, no revise muy bien, prueba con lo que dice bernardoLezama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.js está en el directorio incorrecto, debes subirlo a la carpeta "estática", desde ahí, NodeJS encontrará sin problemas './modulos/server'.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la ruta completa "./contenido/modulos/server".
Además te recomiendo que tengas el archivo de crear el servidor en la carpeta base del proyecto. Y si no es así, al menos el index.js que lo referencia. Esto por motivos de tener el proyecto estructurado, para este tipo de estructura.
Proyecto

- App.js (el servidor)
- carpeta de modulos de nodejs  (para los modulos que uses, se genera sola)
- views (aquí va el html)
- public (aquí una carpeta estatica)

También te recomiendo buscar sobre express ya que estructura el proyecto de una genial manera.